# data.table::melt - variable column converted to factor with variable.factor = FALSE specified

Tags: r, data.table, melt

I am trying to find solution to melt data frame with character colnames, and keep getting factor variables in melted df.

A subset of my data:

```
df <- structure(list(bloc = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L), name = c("Cristina", "Robijn", "Robijn", "Cristina", 
"Robijn", "Cristina", "Cristina", "Robijn", "Robijn", "Cristina", 
"Cristina", "Robijn"), d1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), d7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), d10 = c(1, 0, 
0, 5, 0, 0.1, 1, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0), d13 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 
0.1, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.1), d20 = c(0.1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 50, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 25, 1), d24 = c(75, 5, 25, 100, 25, 75, 95, 5, 5, 100, 75, 
25), d27 = c(75L, 5L, 50L, 100L, 50L, 100L, 100L, 50L, 50L, 100L, 
100L, 25L), d34 = c(75L, 25L, 75L, 100L, 75L, 100L, 100L, 75L, 
75L, 100L, 100L, 50L), d41 = c(75L, 25L, 95L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 95L, 95L, 100L, 100L, 75L), d48 = c(100L, 50L, 95L, 100L, 
75L, 100L, 100L, 75L, 95L, 100L, 100L, 95L), d55 = c(100L, 75L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 43L, 44L, 60L, 62L, 78L, 80L, 95L, 96L, 112L, 117L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the code:

```
data.table::melt(
  df,
  id.vars = c("bloc", "name"),
  variable.name = "time",
  value.name = "severity",
  variable.factor = FALSE
) %>% str()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this is happening, is because `df` is a dataframe. In such cases `melt` from [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) falls back to the behavior of `melt` from [reshape2](/questions/tagged/reshape2) which doesn't have a `variable.factor` argument.

You can see this in the source coude of `data.table::melt`:

```
> data.table::melt
function (data, ..., na.rm = FALSE, value.name = "value") 
{
    if (is.data.table(data)) 
        UseMethod("melt", data)
    else reshape2::melt(data, ..., na.rm = na.rm, value.name = value.name)
}
<bytecode: 0x10f886b88>
<environment: namespace:data.table>
```

Consequently, your code:

```
melt(
  df,
  id.vars = c("bloc", "name"),
  variable.name = "time",
  value.name = "severity",
  variable.factor = FALSE
) %>% str()
```

gives you:

> ```
> 'data.frame': 132 obs. of  4 variables:
>  $ bloc    : int  1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
>  $ name    : chr  "Cristina" "Robijn" "Robijn" "Cristina" ...
>  $ time    : Factor w/ 11 levels "d1","d7","d10",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ severity: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
> ```

However, when wrappring `df` in `setDT`:

```
melt(
  setDT(df),
  id.vars = c("bloc", "name"),
  variable.name = "time",
  value.name = "severity",
  variable.factor = FALSE
) %>% str()
```

you will get the desired output:

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    132 obs. of  4 variables:
>  $ bloc    : int  1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
>  $ name    : chr  "Cristina" "Robijn" "Robijn" "Cristina" ...
>  $ time    : chr  "d1" "d1" "d1" "d1" ...
>  $ severity: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```

Comment: thanks @Jaap, I do not use `data.table` frequently, and as I remember it takes data frame object and treats it as its object, but it might be the other way around.